# How can I prove that fread calls ReadFile and fopen calls CreateFile

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I know it sounds a little stupid but is there a way to prove that on Windows:

- `fopen` function calls winapi function CreateFile (or CreateFileEx)
- `fread` function calls winapi function ReadFile (or ReadFileEx)

If there is a more general way to determine how some C library functions call the winapi functions, I'm also happy with that as an answer.

We're having a debate and I'm interested in some proof. I'm mainly interested in Visual C.

Comment: 1: read the crt source code, 2: use a debugger, 3: learn the Windows API and conclude there's only one way to open a file.  These are things *you* have to do to win this silly dispute.

Comment: Hard to imagine any other way in which `fread` could be implemented. Let's hope MS isn't using the native API!

Comment: They'll use the native APIs in the kernel32 exports..

Comment: @Bukes Of course they will there! They had better not be using native API in the C runtime though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual C comes with the source code for the C runtime library.  Would that settle things?

Answer (score 4):

Break into the application with your debugger and put a breakpoint on the functions you target (they are implemented in `kernel32.dll`). Try to e.g. step over a `fopen` call. If your breakpoint is hit, then `fopen` calls `CreateFile`.